# Does memory_order_seq_cst store guarantee that memory_order_relaxed load will read written value?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, stdatomic

Is in the following code x_value guaranteed to be 42?

```
std::atomic<int> x;

Thread A:
  x.store(42, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  wakeThreadB();

Thread B:
  int x_value = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  assert(x_value == 42);
```

I have tried to test it, and it seemed that thread B always reads correct value. But I'm not sure if it is guaranteed.

Comment: Depends on mechanism you use to wake thread B. If it is some atomic relaxed read/write then there is no guarantee for `x_value` to be 42. That's being said, not sure on what architecture it can fail.

Comment: @emptysamurai: the thing with synchronization is that all the details matter. Without knowing how the wake-up is implemented _exactly_ I don't think your question is answerable.

Comment: In reality I have a quiet complex code, but eventually Thread B is unlocked using condional_variable or there is a memory_order_seq_cst store by thread B to status variable, that ensures that it won't go to sleep and will read value from x

Comment: `std::condition_variable` uses a mutex for synchronization (you need to call lock/unlock in threadA, for it to work properly). So the two threads will synchronize their data. Meaning you can drop the atomic and use regular integer instead and it will be guaranteed to be 42.

Comment: Details matter, but in itself that relaxed load is only guaranteed to be atomic (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order).

Comment: A more strongly-ordered store doesn't become visible any sooner or make other threads wait so they'll see it.  It only makes other operations *in the same thread* wait to get the required ordering.  The only thing that might synchronize between A and B is the `wakeThreadB()`, but you haven't shown how that's implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relaxed load does not synchronize with any other load/store before or after it.

Note also that memory order semantics are about the visibility of *other work* done in relation to the syncronization variable.

So e.g. the following wouldn't be correct:

```cpp
std::atomic<int> x;
int y;

void func_A()
{
  y = 1;
  x.store(42, std::memory_order_seq_cst); // "releases" y = 1
}

void func_B()
{
  while (x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) != 42) {} // does NOT "acquire" anything
  assert(y == 1); // not guaranteed
}

int main()
{
  std::thread a(&func_A), b(&func_B);
  a.join();
  b.join();
}
```

Mandatory note here: "*it always works on my machine*" doesn't make it correct; without synchronization it's a data race, a form of [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

But in your specific case, if by `wakeThreadB()` you mean construction of `std::thread` instance with *Thread B* code as the thread function, then the code is actually correct - `std::thread` creation is a syncronization event (see [[thread.thread.constr]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/thread.thread.constr#5)), so any load in *Thread B* is guaranteed to see everything done before *Thread B* was started.

That means that the atomic store of `x` does not matter at all, the code would be correct even with a non-atomic `int`:

```cpp
void func_B();

int x;
std::thread t;

void func_A()
{
  x = 42;
  t = std::thread(&func_B); // "releases" x = 42
}

void func_B() // "acquires" x = 42
{
  assert(x == 42); // guaranteed success
}

int main()
{
  func_A();
  t.join();
}
```

Similarly, `std::condition_variable` uses a mutex internally and a mutex release/lock is a synchronization event (see [[thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]/25](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/thread.mutex#requirements.mutex-25)), so notifying another thread via a `condition_variable` would also work correctly without the need for any atomics.